# Laravel - Get Route Parameter in a Model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, model-view-controller, laravel-routing

I'm using Laravel 5.5
I have a 'Post' Model. In that model I want to use a Route Parameter (say userId).. I have this id in Post Controller.

```
public function getPosts($userId)
{      
    $posts = Post::latest()->paginate(8);
    return Response::json($posts);
}
```

I want to use the $userId in the Post Model to get some more information.
How do I access this parameter from the Post model? Should I use session to store the userId value and try to use it? Is there any other way?

Comment: call a model function from controller and passed that user id in the function

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `request()` helper:

```
// Get a specific route parameter 
request()->route()->parameter('userId')

// Get all route parameters 
request()->route()->parameters()
```

Say you have a function on a `Post` model:

```
// Post.php

public function doSomething()
{
    if (request()->route()->parameter('userId') === 1) {
        return 'some value';
    }
    return 'another value';
}
```

Comment: `request()->route()` is null

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
request()->route('userId')
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is completely correct, but I just want to add one thing.

**Note:** if You are using:

```
request()->route()->parameter('userId');
```

You might actually get the whole `User` object, not just the `ID`, since Laravel can automatically find the entry in Your `User` table and inject it into the request.

If that happens, You might get some nasty, unlogicall errors, but the **solution is easy**: Just add the `->id` to that `request line` (or whatever the name of Your ID attribute is). Like this:

```
request()->route()->parameter('userId')->id;
```

Comment: The point is the the model is already loaded hence to get the id, you need to retrieve the attribute from that model.

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin yes, exactly :)